# How to use tfidf in text classification?

Tags: nlp, tf-idf

I have a dataset which has 300000 lines, each line of which is an article title, I want to find features like `tf` or `tfidf` of this dataset.
I am able to count the words(tf) in this dataset, such as:
WORD FREQUENCE
`must 10000`
`amazing 9999`

or `word percentage`:
`must 0.2`
`amazing 0.19`

but how to caculate `idf`, I mean I need to find some features to discriminate this dataset from the others? or HOW DOES `tfidf` used in text classification?

Comment: You might be interested in seeing this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54177835/4317058 which gives a simple step-by-step tutorial on how to use `tf-idf` in python and sklearn

Answer (score 0):

In your case a document is a single article title. Therefore the inverse document frequency (IDF) is `log(300000/num(t))`. Where `num(t)` is the number of documents (article titles) that contain the term `t`.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf#Inverse_document_frequency_2